# Php Code Help related to months & date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need a small help about below code. Currently output of the code and attached image is showing rent from specific dates which is chosen by client.
[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa1xh.jpg)
In the image you can see it is showing October 2015, November 2015 & December 2015 from (21/10/2015 till 21/01/2016). But I want to show it in this way October 2015, November 2015, December 2015 & January 2016 from (October 21, 2015 till January 21, 2016)

Can someone help me to fix this code accordingly. thanks

```
      <?php 
        $monthDescription = "";
        //$monthDescription = $rs1['totalmonth'] . " Months";
        if($rs1['totalmonth']==3)
        {
            //$monthDescription = "Quartely";
        }
        else if($rs1['totalmonth']==6)
        {
            //$monthDescription = "Half Yearly";
        }
        else if($rs1['totalmonth']==12)
        {
            //$monthDescription = "Yearly";
        }
        $monthDescription.=' Rent for the month(s) of <br /> ';

        $monthNumber=1;
        if(!is_null($fromdate)){
            $monthNumber=sgetmonth($fromdate);
            $year=sdbyear($fromdate);
        }
        for($i=1;$i<=$rs1['totalmonth'];$i++)
        {
            if($monthNumber==13)
            {
                $monthNumber=1;
                $year = $year + 1;
            }
            $monthName = snummonth($monthNumber);
            if($rs1['totalmonth']==1 || $rs1['totalmonth']==$i)
            {
                $monthDescription.= $monthName . ' ' . $year. ' ';              
            }
            else if($rs1['totalmonth']==($i+1))
            {
                $monthDescription.= $monthName . ' ' . $year. ' & ';
            }
            else
            {
                $monthDescription.= $monthName . ' ' . $year. ', ';
            }
            $monthNumber++;
        }
        if($rs1['totalmonth']>1)
        {
            $fromMonthName="";
            $fromYear="";
            $fromDay="";
            $toMonthName="";
            $toYear="";
            $toDay="";
            if(!is_null($fromdate)){
                $fromMonthName=sdbmonth($fromdate);
                $fromYear=sdbyear($fromdate);
                $fromDay=sgetday($fromdate);
            }       
            if(!is_null($todate)){
                $toMonthName=sdbmonth($todate);
                $toYear=sdbyear($todate);
                $toDay=sgetday($todate);
            }       
            $monthDescription.= ' from ('.sdate($fromdate). ' till '.sdate($todate).')';
        }
    ?>
      <?php echo ''.$rs1['modelnumber'] . ' Advance '.$monthDescription; 
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It looks like what you want depends on other variables that are not defined in your code. For example, you have to change the `$rs1['totalmonth']` month variable. But this variable is not defined in your code. Where does `$rs1` come from? It looks like it is from a database.